# Checkout and Transaction API Permissions error

Tags: api, transactions, checkout, square-connect

I am currently trying to create a transaction or checkout from Postman, I set the Header with a full access token but the API always response:

```
{
    "errors": [
    {
            "category": "AUTHENTICATION_ERROR",
            "code": "FORBIDDEN",
            "detail": "You have insufficient permissions to perform that action."
        }
    ]
}
```

Attach the OAuth screen.[Permissions image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF1ia.png)

and the postman request.  https://www.getpostman.com/collections/4fe6fec54384fc10d152

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is due to you not being in one of the countries currently available to Square's APIs: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/faq-international-availability?q=country. You will not be able to make payments using the API when outside of the countries listed above.

Furthermore, you should never share your personal access token with anyone (which you show in your screenshot). Please change this immediately, by navigating to your Square dashboard and clicking "Replace" on your "Credentials" tab.